# OSX - Getting an image loaded in a WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I have a WebView that is loading a webpage. I want to save all the images loaded in the webpage, but I want to save them as each image is finished downloading through the delegate method:

`-(void) webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource`

How would I do this? I just want to avoid the situation where I grab the image src's and then redownload the images. Maybe my approach is wrong? Maybe save the images through `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]`? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebKit, How do I get the contents of the resource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155359/webkit-how-do-i-get-the-contents-of-the-resource)

Comment: That's right. I found that thread and have been waiting to self-answer but don't have enough reputation to do it. If you want to provide that as the answer, I'll happily mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155359/in-webkit-how-do-i-get-the-content-of-a-resource) helped out a lot in giving me some breakthroughs for my final solution. I ended up executing some javascript to grab the src attribute from the img tag. Then, every time the `-(void) webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource` method is called, it checks for `[dataSource subresourceForURL:url]`. If it returns true, then it performs the save. Here's the full code:

```
-(void) webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:/* javascript to grab src */]];
    if ([dataSource subresourceForURL:url]) {
        NSData *dataToSave = [[dataSource subresourceForURL:url] data];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!