# How to intercept raw data that refreshes a Flash SWF player at the client side?

Tags: windows

I found this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494831/intercept-web-requests-from-a-webview-flash-plugin`

...and it appears to answer what I need. Alas I'm not on a Mac. Is anything analogous to an NSURL object available to me on MS Windows? Or any other way to get at an updated data stream?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

http://getfirebug.com/ lets you look at requests made by flash